# change event in backbone relational not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I am working with backbone relational with HasMany relationship. Add event gets fired but change event does not.

```
Model1 = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot: '/Leve1/',

    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this, 'add:relatedModels', this.relationModelAdd);
        this.listenTo(this, 'change:relatedModels', this.relationModelChange);
    },

    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'relatedModels',
        relatedModel: 'InnerModel'
    }],

    relationModelAdd: function () {
        alert("Add in related model");
    },

    relationModelChange: function () {
        alert("Change in related model");
    }
});

InnerModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot: '/Level2/'         
});

var outerModel = new Model1({
    id: 'model1',
});
var innerModel = new InnerModel({
    id: 'model11',          
});

outerModel.get('relatedModels').add(innerModel);

innerModel.set({
    id: 'model13'
});
```

Change event with HasOne relationship works but not with HasMany.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, `change` event does not fire on a outer-model `Model1` if change occurs in any model `InnerModel` inside a HasMany relation's collection. See the issue in Backbone.RelationalModel on GitHub: [Change events not being fired on collection change](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/56). The issue was closed by the author who said:

> I don't think firing a `change` event for every modification on any relation by defaults would be a good idea, but something like that is pretty easy to do by adding a helper method to  `Backbone.RelationalModel`, since `this._relations` actually does give you the related model or collection. Quick first attempt that you could build from:
>
> ```
> Backbone.RelationalModel.prototype.bindRelationEvents = function() {
>     var dit = this;
>     _.each( this.getRelations(), function( relation ) {
>         relation.related && relation.related.bind( 'all', function() {
>             dit.trigger.apply( dit, arguments );
>             // Or even simply `dit.render()`, if the number of events is reasonable...
>         } );
>     });
> };
> ```
>
> then call `this.bindRelationEvents` for objects you'd like to receive all events from their relations as well.